# 'MyFile' was not declared in this scope error in C++

Tags: c++, file, scope, codeblocks, declaration

I'm currently working on a project for my college, using C++ and CodeBlocks 20.03. I'm trying to read from a text file and assign its values to arrays in my program. However, the system keep throwing the error 'MyFile' was not declared in this scope. Does anybody knows how to solve this issue?

I tried to relocate the MyFile.close() statement closer but it's not working. Also, I don't know if it would be good to move the fstream setence within the while loop, since in here I'm getting the error too.

```
while(opcion_consulta!='N'){
        cout << "Favor ingrese el código del producto que desea consultar: ";
        cin >> codigo_producto_buscado;
        try{
            ifstream MyFile("Productos.txt");
        }
        catch(...){
            cout << "No se pudo acceder al inventario" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        codigo_temporal[tamanno_inventario];
        nombre_temporal[tamanno_inventario];
        cantidad_temporal[tamanno_inventario];
        cout << "Buscando" << endl;
        while(verificar_busqueda!='N'){
            for(int i=0; i<=(sizeof(tamanno_inventario)/sizeof(int)); i++){
                MyFile >> codigo_temporal[i] >> nombre_temporal[i] >> cantidad_temporal[i];
                if(codigo_temporal[i]==codigo_producto_buscado){
                    cout << "Producto encontrado" << endl;
                    cout << nombre_temporal[i] << endl;
                    cout << "Cantidad disponible: " << cantidad_temporal[i];
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "Producto no encontrado. Desea volver a buscar (S/N): ";
                    cin >> verificar_busqueda;
                    if(verificar_busqueda!='S' && verificar_busqueda!='N'){
                        cout << "Valor inválido. Reingrese S o N: ";
                        cin >> verificar_busqueda;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    MyFile.close();
    cout << "Presione S si desea consultar otro producto: ";
    cin >> opcion_consulta;
    if(opcion_consulta!='S' && opcion_consulta!='N'){
        cout << "Valor inválido. Reingrese S o N: ";
        cin >> verificar_busqueda;
    }
}
```

My project is in Spanish, so that is why the variable names are on this language

Comment: Please post a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) / [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that people can cut'n'paste, compile and test themselves, not just a snippet of code.  Btw: `MyFile` only exists in the `try {` scope of your code. When you try to call `MyFile.close()` later, the object is no longer in scope.

Comment: Your `for` loop looks very wrong. I'm not sure what `tamanno_inventario` is. I'm not sure what `codigo_temporal[tamanno_inventario];` is doing. But it looks like either you're declaring an array incorrectly or using an incorrect value for your loop index or both.

Comment: Side note: Code::Blocks is a tool that sits over top of a separate [toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain) (though in the case of Windows installs it often ships with mingw of one variant or another) so saying you use Code::Blocks is often not as useful as stating which toolchan and version of the toolchain Code::Blocks has been configured to use.

Answer (score 1):

The name `MyFile` is declared within the `try` block:

```
try{
    ifstream MyFile("Productos.txt");
}
```

So outside the `try` block, it is invisible.

You could declare the name before the `try` block, and within the `try` block open the corresponding file:

```
ifstream MyFile;
try{
    MyFile.open("Productos.txt");
}
```

---

Also, as it was written in a comment, in this `for` loop:

```
 for(int i=0; i<=(sizeof(tamanno_inventario)/sizeof(int)); i++){
```

it seems you need to use this condition:

```
i < (sizeof(tamanno_inventario)/sizeof(int))
^^^^
```

instead of:

```
i <= (sizeof(tamanno_inventario)/sizeof(int))
^^^^^
```

Comment: Note: while this does fix the problem, the entire `try` block is pointless here. Unless exceptions are turned on via [`exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method, no stream operation will throw anything. `ifstream MyFile("Productos.txt"); if(!MyFile){/*log and exit*/}` would be correct way to handle error on opening file.